# passing parameters

Tags: expansion, parameters

I have seen some examples that you can pass `parameters` to build a template such as `\int_step_inline`: you can write `#1` to represent the current value of the loop. I wonder how it works and have some try.

As I know from `TeXbyTopic`, in every expansion, `#1` is replaced by `<parameter token1>` and `##` is replaced by `#` (*here is a question, how is `###` and `####`
replaced?*).

But I do not sure what happens when `#1` is passed as a parameter of a macro. It seems that `#1` just replaces `#n` of the macro.

I have following example.

```
\def\a#1{\def\b##1{#1}}
```

If I have the right idea. `\a{*#1*}` is expande to `\def\b#1{*#1*}`, then `\b{test}` will get `*test*`. From the output, it seems that I'm right, but I want to know if I really get the right idea or there is some extra information that I ignored.

Comment: `###` the first `##` is replaced by `#` and the remaining `#` would generate an error unless followed by `#` or `1`-`9`,  `####` is just two `##` each replaced by `#` so you get `##`.

Comment: Related: [Double hashes inside macro definition?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be complete:

- In `<parameter text>` like the `#1#2` in `\def\x#1#2{...}`, `#` followed by a digit 1--9 denotes a parameter. And any other use cases of `#` raise error.

  - A special case is a `<parameter text>` ends with `#`. For example, `\def\x#1#{...}`. This means `#1` is delimited by `{`.
- In `<replacement text>`, `#1` to `#9` is treated corresponding parameter token and `##` is treated as single `#`. Any other use cases of `#` raise error.
- In other cases, for example as macro argument (`\a{#1}`), nothing special happens on `#`.

So you may use `\def\a#1{\def\b##1{\def\c####1####{...}}}`.